# Why does typeof Array returns "function" and typeof [array variable] returns an "Object"?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had a chance to met this question but unable to find an answer.

```
var arr = [];
```

Why does `typeof Array` returns `"function"` and `typeof arr` returns an `"Object"`?

Can anyone explain please.

Comment: Because `Array` is a constructor function for array instances, and array instances are ultimately objects ([there is no "array" return value for typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Description))

Comment: You can *call* `Array`: `arr = new Array()`. Since it's callable, it's a function.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Could you please elaborate.. Also, not sure why typeof arr is an Object. We have 'array' as datatype.. So it suppose to return 'array'.

Comment: Every array is an instance of the `Array` "class", and therefore it's an object. To check if an object is an array you should use something like `Array.isArray` instead of `typeof`

Comment: @GreenComputers there is no datatype called "array" in JavaScript. You have objects that inherit from the Array prototype.

Comment: @Ayrton *Every array is an instance of the Array "class", and therefore it's an object.*  <-- No. JavaScript doesn't have classes. Every array is an instance of an Array object created by the `Array` constructor function.

Comment: That's why I used "quotes", buddy

Comment: @ScottMarcus Very clear. Thank you.

Comment: @Ayrton JavaScript can be confusing as it is. It's best not to introduce words that don't apply to it. And, you didn't put quotes around it in your answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `typeof Array`, it means that you are getting type of constructor function. As `class` is under the hood is constructor function. Let me show an example:

```
class Person {
    constructor(firstName, lastName, address) {
        this.firstName= firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address= address;
    }

    getFullName () {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName ;
    }
}
```

and to create an instance of the class:

```
let car = new Person ("Jon", "Freeman", "New York");
```

In the above code, we've created a variable `car` which references to function construtor defined in the class:

```
function Person (firstName, lastName, address) {
        this.firstName = firstName,
        this.lastName = lastName,
        this.address = address,
        this.getFullName = function () {
            return this.firstName+ " " + this.lastName;
        }
}
```

So this is a reason why `typeof Array` returns `function`.